# Meaning of Files/Folders With a Red/Gray X on Them

Tags: icons

There are some files and folders that have a red X on them. What are those? What does that red X represent?

[image]

Comment: @Zanna I mentioned the root folder as an example...My question is general about files and folders with the same icon.

Comment: Same applies to all

Comment: @Zanna I see...

Comment: I think you are using a modified icon theme; the X is not red, it's grey (at least in 16.04).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Indeed I use. I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red x means that you have no access (Permissions) to these files and folders as the user currently running nautilus (the file manager nowadays called stupidly Files).